# What is the difference between registering a UDF using PySpark's 'registerJavaFunction' and Spark SQL's 'CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION' in Spark 3?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with a code base in which, in Python files, UDFs are registered in two ways for use in Spark SQL statements. Is there a difference between these two? Is one preferable in some situations?

- PySpark: `spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("[UDF]", "[Java Path]", [Return Type])`
- SQL: `spark.sql("create temporary function [Func] as [Java Path]")`

Both of these will be followed by SQL statements using the UDFs in the format `spark.sql('[SELECT statement using UDF]')`

I'm unclear on the difference between "registering" and "creating"

- [`registerJavaFunction`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration.registerJavaFunction): *Register a Java user-defined function as a SQL function.*
- [`CREATE [TEMPORARY] FUNCTION`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-function.html): *The CREATE FUNCTION statement is used to create a temporary or permanent function in Spark.*

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using python, please stick with either a SQL or Python function.  The later uses udf and udf.register from pyspark.sql.function.

I wrote an article on this topic recently on MS SQL TIPS.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7580/scalar-using-table-user-defined-spark-functions-azure-databricks/

There are new declarators that you can use also - @udf and @pandas_udf.

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html

The only real use case for the java functions is if you want to re-use java code.  In that case, I suggest using Scala as the notebook language.  For instance, I have a old wheel (binary) that I want to install on the cluster and use.

In real life, I stick with the python code since it is quicker to develop.